# How do I create an histogram in R from a data set in an excel sheet?

Tags: r, histogram

[enter image description here][1]
I have this data set (107 observations) from an excel sheet and I would like to turn it into an histogram in R. Could you please help me ?

Comment: It is certainly possible.

To read in excel data you could use `read_excel()` from `readxl` (part of the wonderful `tidyverse`).

Probably have some wrangling to do then but for plotting you could use `geom_histogram` from `ggplot2` (again as part of the `tidyverse`) or `hist` from base R

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Without more detail, I fear your question will soon be closed.  Also, please remember that SO is not a code writing service.  It is a community of those willing to help resolve problems in the code you have written yourself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.